# Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: No route to host

Tags: facebook, sdk

I follow this tutorial for auto post on facebook wall.
http://www.tricksofit.com/2015/08/auto-post-on-facebook-using-php-sdk-v5

I have tested on my localhost and the result is ok. It works.

but when i uploaded on my website. It gets an error.

"Facebook SDK returned an error: Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: No route to host"

I try to search the information on the google, but still confused.

Can someone give me a suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Your server can not find a route to Facebook’s servers – so go ask your server admin to look into the problem and fix it. Btw., I hope you are aware that you are not allowed to auto-post anything on user timeline – every single post must be actively triggered by the user, and the message must be a 100% user-generated, i.e. typed in by the user.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I asked admin and they told me nothing is changed. However, the post that I post is only url for my website that 1 post per 5 hours.

Comment: That sounds like the very definition of spam. Who of your friends wants to see your website URL in their newsfeed every five hours …? Probably no one.

Answer (score -3):

This problem was from Facebook side and then graph.facebook.com was temporarily unavailable but it had been resolved by Facebook team. If this problem is still occurring on your side then please provide more detail with code you are using.

Thanks
Divanshu Verma

Comment: I just used the code from the url i posted above. I tested on my localhost and my server and the result is different.